# Why doesn't SQL Server's OBJECT_ID(NVARCHAR) take a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So why doesn't this work?

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
    DECLARE @tn NVARCHAR
    SET @tn = 'MyTable'
    SELECT OBJECT_ID(@tn)
```

When this does:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
    SELECT OBJECT_ID('MyTable')
```

I need to pass a variable into this function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does.

```
declare @name sysname = N'sys.objects';
select object_id(@name);


-----------
-385

(1 row(s) affected)
```

In your example you declare a variable of length 1 (since you [omit the length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)). `OBJECT_ID(N'M')` finds nothing and returns NULL.

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the
>   CAST function, the default length is 30.

Comment: Well I see the answer ... but as you can see the problem was declaring the variable as a NVARCHAR vs a SYSNAME.

Comment: @davesbrain: sysname is just nvarchar with some other stuff.  Namely, a specified length and, iirc, non-nullability. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're missing the size on your `NVARCHAR`.

This works:

```
DECLARE @tn NVARCHAR(20)
SET @tn = 'MyTable'
SELECT OBJECT_ID(@tn)
```